# gnuplot - line 0 invalid command

Tags: python, gnuplot

I keep getting this when trying to plot my data with:

```
gnuplot < data.txt
```

**code**:

```
f.write(str(i) + " " + str(delta1) + " "+ str(delta2) + "\n")
```

**output**:

```
gnuplot > 100 0.000235080718994 0.000234842300415
         ^
         line 0: invalid command
```

Any ideas as to why? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to pipe in the data file. You can pipe in a file with commands. Something like `plot data.txt using 0:1`

Comment: Hi ilia, I'm a little confused as to what piping is. This is a homework assignment and the professor told listed the format `gnuplot < file.txt` which is why I used that. I'm not sure the correct way to go about it

Comment: `gnuplot -e "plot 'data.txt' using 0:1:2" --persist`

Comment: Tried that and got - `Failed to initialize wxWidgets line 0: warning: Too many axis ticks requested (>5)` Any idea?

Comment: `gnuplot -e "set terminal png; plot 'data.txt' using 0:1:2" --persist > out.png`

Comment: That worked! One more thing if you will, can I view this with any command? Or do I need to open the file itself? Thanks!

Comment: @iliacholy Thanks for helping out the OP. There seem to be quite a few basic questions going around on the `gnuplot` tag. As the  OP mentioned this and others maybe from a homework assignment. Thinking about what would be the best strategy for these questions, any ideas?!